# Equal operation in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Hey I am trying to compare two values against another value,
is it possible to just write `A=B=3` instead of `A=3 AND B=3`?

Comment: No, that's not possible.

Comment: `CASE WHEN (COLUMN1 = COLUMN2 AND COLUMN1 = 3 AND COLUMN2 = 3) THEN '1' ELSE '0' END AS MyResult` maybe ?

Comment: @Nickname_used: the CASE is unnecessary the expression `COLUMN1 = COLUMN2 AND COLUMN1 = 3 AND COLUMN2 = 3` yields a boolan value. No need to convert that back into a string. Note that `AND COLUMN2 = 3` is actually unnecessary as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not possible.

If you want to avoid writing the constant multiple times, you can use:

```
3 = all(array[a,b])
```

alternatively using standard SQL

```
3 = all( values(a),(b) )
```

Or use an AND condition:

```
a = b and a = 3
```